# PusherApp presence errors

Tags: websocket

I'm using PusherApp, and I'm having issues with using presence channels. I'm authenticating, and passing this along to the "send" function. Attached are two screen shots. I have no idea how the formatting got messed up as the screen shots will show. You won't see the auth string portion as I took it out only for the screenshot but I know it's in the format:

applicationKey:signature

I took the sample signature for ruby and I generated it in .net and its the same so my procedure is correct I think.

Any ideas?

Thanks much,

David Whitten

Answer (score 0):

David eventually answered this question himself and provided [Pusher](http://pusher.com) with the code. This has been rolled into the [Pusher .NET REST Library](https://github.com/grahamscott/pusherrestdotnet).

Specifically, the code for presence authentication can be seen [here](https://github.com/grahamscott/pusherrestdotnet/blob/master/PusherRESTDotNet/Authentication/PusherAuthenticationHelper.cs#L36).